# CSV Headers in python

Tags: python, csv

I have multi-able Keys for json file.These keys are different from file to file. Something like that,

```
{
    "F2N-1": [
        {
            "neName": "F2N-1",
            "equipmentName": "2UC400-5-10",
            "equipmentType": "Card",
            "provisionedType": "2UC400", ]
        }

   "F2N-2" : [
        {
            "neName": "F2N-2",
            "equipmentName": "2UC400-5-10",
            "equipmentType": "Card",
            "provisionedType": "2UC400", ]
        }
```

... and so on

i need to create a csv headers with these variable Keys like this :

```
                       F2N-1        F2N-2

neName                 F2N-1         F2N-2
equipmentName          2UC400-5-10    2UC400-5-10
equipmentType
```

and so on. would this happen using csv module ?

i tried ,

```
file =open(r'D:\tmp\json.txt')
file =  json.load(file)

print(file.items)



for key, value in file.items():
    with open(r'D:\tmp\inventory.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = [key]
        print(fieldnames)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        csvfile.close()
```

Comment: have you tried `pandas`?

Comment: how can i do that with pandas ?

Comment: You can use `pandas.read_json` for read your json file. For the column index, juts using `set_index` then swap index to column using transpose